# Given natural $m$ and $n$, if $m^{2023}+2024m+n^2$ is divisible by $mn$, and $m>n$, then $m$ is a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, square-numbers

> Given $m, n$ natural numbers, $m^{2023}+2024m+n^2$ is divisible by $mn$, and $m>n$, prove that $m$ is perfect square.

I tried considering $m$ being a multiple of $3$, $1+$ a multiple of $3$, and $2+$ a multiple of $3$, but I do not know how to continue.

Can someone give me an idea? Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts, and to indicate the source of this problem.  Questions involving the current year often feature in competitions and such.

Comment: Note that if $(m,n)=(2,2)$ then $4=2\times 2$ divides your expression, but $2$ isn't  a  perfect square.

Comment: You are right. Sorry, it also says that m is greater than n

Comment: meanwhile, what is the source of the problem?

Comment: I do not know. I just received a photo of it and it does not show the source

Comment: can you add the image? Images of common problems are available on the internet and may be used to identify the source (and the solution, if present at the source)

Comment: also, are you given that $\gcd(m,2024) = 1$? It becomes trivial then

Comment: The tag divisor sum is not appropriate for this question. Number theory is a better option

Comment: I can add an image but it is not in English. Also, I am not given that gcd(m, 2024)=1

Comment: $m=32,n=16$ seems to be the smallest counterexample

Comment: you should post this as an answer @Sil

Comment: @DS I'll wait a bit in case OP will clarify some missing assumptions (although post is not newest...). Plus there is already counterexample answer so this just gives different numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a counterexample: when $m=3^2\cdot253$ and $n=3\cdot253$, it gives us $m^{2023}+2024m+n^2=9^{2023}\cdot253^{2023}+81\cdot253^2$ which is divisible by $27\cdot253^2=mn$. But, $m=3^2\cdot253$ is not a perfect square.